# Parameters in XSLT and their context

Tags: xml, xslt

I understand this topic very loosely, but effectively I need to define a parameter and have it's value change, so I've opted to put it at the top of a for-each loop making it local, but then when I dive into a nested tag, for example anoter for each loop, I can no longer access the local variable from the one higher up. My question is do they not get inherited by the new nested loop? can they not see the variables even though they should be within scope?

```
<xsl:for-each select="ns0:BxfMessage/ns0:BxfData/ns0:Content" >
  <xsl:if test="string(@version) = 'Series'">
    <SERIES>
      <xsl:param name="SeriesHouseNumber">
        <xsl:value-of select="string(ns0:BxfMessage/ns0:BxfData/ns0:Content/ns0:ProgramContent/ns0:ContentMetaData/ns0:ContentId/ns0:HouseNumber)"/>
      </xsl:param> 

      <UniqueIDFieldName>
        <xsl:value-of select="string(ns0:ProgramContent/ns0:ContentMetaData/ns0:ContentId/ns0:HouseNumber)"/>
      </UniqueIDFieldName>

      <PROGID1>
        <xsl:value-of select="string(ns0:ProgramContent/ns0:ContentMetaData/ns0:ContentId/ns0:HouseNumber)"/>
      </PROGID1>

      <SER_TITLE>
        <xsl:value-of select="string(ns0:ProgramContent/ns0:ContentMetaData/ns0:Name)"/>
      </SER_TITLE>

      <xsl:for-each select="../ns0:Content" >
        <xsl:if test="string(@version) = 'Title'">
          <CHILDREN>
            <EPISODE>
              <xsl:if test="$SeriesHouseNumber = string(ns0:ProgramContent/ns0:ContentMetaData/ns0:ContentId/ns0:AlternateId)">
                <ORIG_CT_TITLE>
                  <xsl:value-of select="string(ns0:ProgramContent/ns0:ContentMetaData/ns0:Name)"/>
                </ORIG_CT_TITLE>
```

the series house number variable can't be accessed which is causing me pain inside the nested for each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<xsl:variable>` instead of `<xsl:param>`.

```
<xsl:variable
    name="SeriesHouseNumber"
    select="string(ns0:BxfMessage/ns0:BxfData/ns0:Content/ns0:ProgramContent/ns0:ContentMetaData/ns0:ContentId/ns0:HouseNumber)"/>
```

If you still wish to use a parameter (so you can substitute it later), put the `<xsl:param>` immediately inside your `<xsl:template>`, not nested inside other elements.

Comment: How would I update the string thats stored in a paramter after it's created? I tried using xsl:value of but that just compared it and output a boolean to the output file for me. I shall try a variable instead however and see if can be accessed  from the nested loop, cheers

Comment: You can't modify a variable that is already declared. But if the variable is inside a loop, it will be declared anew on each iteration. Similar to variables marked with `readonly` or `final` in other languages.

Comment: Yeah I know, it really irritates me I can't modify a variable after its been declared but I've figure out a way round it cheers :)